# How to properly splice array item by id

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple popup component that get's called on a click event in some places in my app. The popups get created on click and are pushed in an array, that is later forEach-ed and displayed so that when the user clicks on a button multiple times multiple popups are displayed. The success ones disappear and the red ones disappear once someone clicks on the X, I achieve that by splicing them from the array, but if a user generated 5 popups and clicks the X the next popup gets closed, not the one that the user has clicked on, so it seems that I am not targeting the specific popup order in the array but the next, how can I properly target the exact clicked modal so that it gets closed and not the one that is next in line, what am I doing wrong here? How should I splice the array properly so that I target the exact pushed modal and not the rest?

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <div 
      v-for="item in array" 
      :key="item.id"
      :class="['popUp', `popUp--type--${item.popUpTypeType}`]" 
    >
      <div class="popUp-side">
        <p class="exclamation-mark">!</p>
      </div>
      <h5 class="popUp-message">{{item.message}}</h5>
      <div class="popUp-side">
        <p class="closing-x" @click="closeMessage" v-if="item.popUpTypeType === 'danger'">X</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
   name: 'popUp',
   data: () => ({
    array:[],
  }),
  methods: {
    removepopUpType() {
       var self = this;
       var id = Math.round( Math.random()*1e13 );
       var index = self.array.map(x => {
       return x.id;
       }).indexOf(id);
        self.array.splice(index, 1);
    },
    callpopUpType(obj){
      var newpopUpType = {
            popUpTypeType: obj.type,
            message: obj.message,
            id: obj.id
          };
      if(obj.type === 'success'){
       setTimeout(this.removepopUpType, 2000)
      }
      this.array.push(newpopUpType);
    },

    closeMessage() {
    this.removepopUpType()
    },

  },
  created() {
    this.$root.$on('call-popUp', this.callpopUpType);
  },
  destroyed(){
    this.$root.$off('call-popUp', this.callpopUpType);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is so _exact_  (_"so that I target the **exact** pushed modal"_) about `Math.round( Math.random()*1e13 )`? And `self.array.splice(index)` doesn't remove one element only.

Comment: Given `id` is unlikely to match anything, `index` will just be `-1`. Passing `-1` to `splice` will just remove the last item from the array.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a bit of unusual code in the example, so I may be missing something, but couldn't you just pass the `item` to the method.

```
<p
  v-if="item.popUpTypeType === 'danger'"
  class="closing-x" 
  @click="closeMessage(item)"
>X</p>
```

and then

```
closeMessage(item) {
  const index = this.array.indexOf(item);
  if (index >= 0) this.array.splice(index, 1)
},
```